# Using the output from mysqldiff.exe to transform database2 to match database1

Tags: mysql, schema, data-synchronization

This question is related to another I had asked earlier here: [Passing passwords more securely to mysql utilities on the command line](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98258/passing-passwords-more-securely-to-mysql-utilities-on-the-command-line).

I have recently been trying to use `mysqldiff.exe`, part of `MySQL Utilities` group of tools. My goal is to spot any schema differences between database1 and database2, then going by what it says "on the label", I should be able to obtain statements that can transform either of the databases to match the other.

Here's example output I obtained by comparing `database1.clients` and `database2.clients`.

```
# WARNING: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
# server1 on localhost: ... connected.
# server2 on localhost: ... connected.
# Comparing database1.clients to database2.clients            [FAIL]
# Object definitions differ. (--changes-for=server1)
#

--- database1.clients
+++ database2.clients
@@ -61,4 +61,4 @@
   CONSTRAINT `clients_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`state_code`) REFERENCES `states` (`state_code`) ON DELETE
SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
   CONSTRAINT `clients_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`rel_id`) REFERENCES `religions` (`rel_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON
UPDATE CASCADE,
   CONSTRAINT `clients_ibfk_9` FOREIGN KEY (`nationality_id`) REFERENCES `country` (`Code`) ON DELETE SET NULL
 ON UPDATE CASCADE
-) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8041 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
+) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=691802 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
Compare failed. One or more differences found.
```

Problem is, I was expecting the output to be usable SQL statements, so I can then run this on the relevant side of the compare. How can I use this tool to perform database schema synchronization as I described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it appears on the manual, use the option [`--difftype=sql`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/mysqldiff.html#option_mysqldiff_difftype) in order to obtain the results as `ALTER TABLE`s.

You have [an example on a recent MySQL Performance Blog post](http://www.percona.com/blog/2015/04/15/checking-table-definition-consistency-mysqldiff/):

```
$ mysqldiff --force --difftype=sql \
--server1=root:msandbox@127.0.0.1:21489 \
--server2=root:msandbox@127.0.0.1:21490 \
employees:employees
```

Comment: Outch!! And I missed that? Need to change my lenses! Thank you so much, bro!

Comment: However, having gone through your suggested `percona.com` blog. I wonder if my bublbe is burst. It worries me when it says the diff SQL statements is "not perfect", and I "need to visually check the output before applying the changes". How does that sound when you have hundreds or thousands of query lines in the diff output?